# three.js additional texture color

Tags: three.js, textures, blender, voronoi

I have a mesh with a base color and want to add an additional color. The intensity the additional color shall be added with is given by a (Voronoi) texture.

Is this currently possible in three.js?

If not: What's the best way to add this functionality? Adding an extra parameter "textureColor" or the like to the material (and picking it up in the fragment shader)? Or adding a "color" parameter to the texture? The latter would be more like Blender: In Blender a texture is not only a map, but also has attributes, e.g. R, G, and B.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your best bet is writing a custom shader and use `ShaderMaterial`.